# .gitignore not working. My environment variables are being pushed to my repo when they should be un-tracked

Tags: git, environment-variables, gitignore

Common sense says don't push environment variables on a public git repo. I always make sure to add my environment variable to my .gitignore file.

This time I do everything correct and when I do a git push files the environment variable is in the repo! I immediately remove it. I go back for a re-do.

I called my environment variable `important.env`

The un-tracked file under **git status** shows `important.env.env` Why does it have **.env** twice under the un-tracked filename?

Comment: Because you're on Windows and are hiding known file extensions? Shouldn't matter for .gitignore anyway, what entry do you have in there?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Can you share the filenames and the .gitignore file?

Comment: The filename is "important.env" which contains my api keys. I created the .gitignore file in git bash terminal using "touch .gitignore". I then go into the .gitignore and type the file I want untracked and save. This is how I always setup my un-tracked files. But for some reason git adds an additional .env at the end. So it has "important.env.env"

Comment: Check the files you have on disk (for example,: from `git-bash` run `ls`). Chances are you have two files : important.env and important.env.env

Answer (score 2):

> The un-tracked file under git status shows `important.env.env`

It depends on how the file was created (with which editor).
Sometime, said editor will add automatically an extension to the filename (even when said filename already have an extension)

Rename it, and check if the file is currently ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- important.env
```

If the result is empty, remove it from Git first:

```
git rm --cached -- important.env
git commit -m "Remove env file"
git push
```